# UIPageViewController with preview of next Page

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I really need to apply a `UIPageViewController` into my app in order to display n objects in a horizontal scrolled view. By now, everything it's ok.

But the problem is that layout is custom and I need to show a bit of "next page" (Something like image below):

[image]

I've tried to set `clipToBounds` false to `PageViewController` and also to controllers that are loaded but it seems not work.

So I would like know if is there some way to do it using `UIPageViewController` or I should change approach and use another component like `UICollectionView` (Way that I wouldn't like to follow in this case).

Comment: Have you ever found a solution on this?

Comment: @Hemang...
I have not found a solution yet. For my current project I have used iCarousel (https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel)

Comment: Thanks for the respond.